# tikz label coordinates using mathematical expression from foreach variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, labels, foreach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {-3.0,-2.8,...,1.8}
        \draw[thin] (0,0) ++(\x,2) rectangle ++(0.2, 0.2) coordinate [pos=.5] (one\xi);

    \foreach \x [count=\ai from 1] in {1,0.8,...,0.2}
        \foreach \y [count=\bi from 0] in {1,0.8,...,0.2}
            \draw[thin] (0,0) ++(-\x, -\y) rectangle ++(0.2, 0.2) coordinate [pos=.5] (two);
            %label should be \ai + (\bi * 5)
    \foreach \x  in {1,...,25}      
            \draw[->] (one\x) -- (two\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the above stated example is an error where the name range from `two1` to `two25` is unknown. How can i rewrite this line:

```
\draw[thin] (0,0) ++(-\x, -\y) rectangle ++(0.2, 0.2) coordinate [pos=.5] (two);
```

so that names are set from `two1` to `two25`. I would like to calculate the names based on

```
\ai + (\bi * 5)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to calculate the value and truncate it (`1.0` → `1`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {-3.0,-2.8,...,1.8}
        \draw[thin] (0,0) ++(\x,2) rectangle ++(0.2, 0.2) coordinate [pos=.5] (one\xi);

    \foreach \x [count=\ai from 1] in {1,0.8,...,0.2}
        \foreach \y [count=\bi from 0] in {1,0.8,...,0.2}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yi{\ai + 5*\bi} % <-- here we go! ------ and there: --- vvv
            \draw[thin] (0,0) ++(-\x, -\y) rectangle ++(0.2, 0.2) coordinate [pos=.5] (two\yi);
    \foreach \x  in {1,...,25}      
            \draw[->] (one\x) -- (two\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]